# Ubicar botón al final de un snackbar

Tags: css, angular

Tengo un snackbar con botones, en el css del snackbar puse esto para que queden centrados:

```
.snackbar {
 background-color: rgba($color: #323232, $alpha: 0.8);
 height: 15px !important;
 display: flex !important;
 list-style: none !important;
 justify-content: center 
 align-content: center; 
 align-items: center;
 padding: top right bottom left;
 max-width: 1500px !important; 
 min-width: 1300px !important; 
}
```

Hasta ahí todo perfecto.
El problema surge cuando quiero agregar el botón para Cerrar. Este debería ir al final del snackBar.
Pero no encuentro forma de hacerlo, me queda centrado siempre.
Tampoco puedo moverlo explícitamente con un left porque al ser una lista dinámica la cantidad de botones pueden cambiar, eso hace que me mueve a lugares indeseados.
Alguna idea? gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba ha añadirle una posición absoluta al botón de Cerrar.
Y al snackBar una posición relativa y padding del lado al que lo quieras posicionar.

Así puedes tener todos los botones que sean ya que el snackBar respetará el espacio necesario del botón Cerrar.

```css
.snackbar {
 /* height: 15px !important; */
 display: flex !important;
 list-style: none !important;
 justify-content: center 
 align-content: center; 
 align-items: center;
 padding: top right bottom left;
 /* max-width: 1500px !important; 
 min-width: 1300px !important;
 */
}
body {
  background: #DDD;
  margin: 50px 0;
}
.snackbar {
  background-color: tomato !important;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 70px; //Mismo width del botón cerrar
}
.cerrar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="snackbar">
  <li>Boton 1</li>
  <li>Boton 2</li>
  <li>Boton 3</li>
  <li>Boton 4</li>
  <li>Boton 5</li>
  <li>Boton 6</li>
  <li>Boton 7</li>
  <li>Boton 8</li>
  <li>Boton 9</li>
  <li>Boton 10</li>
  <li>Boton 1</li>
  <li>Boton 2</li>
  <li>Boton 3</li>
  <li>Boton 4</li>
  <li>Boton 5</li>
  <li>Boton 6</li>
  <li>Boton 7</li>
  <li>Boton 8</li>
  <li>Boton 9</li>
  <li>Boton 10</li>
  <li class="cerrar"><button>Cerrar</button></li>
</ul>
```